# Mouse move event for polyline vertex in google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polyline, google-polyline

I would like to show an info window when I'm moving a vertex on an editable polyline.
This info will show the distance and heading to the prior vertex on the polyline. When I drop the vertex, the info window must be closed.
The problem is polyline hasn't a drag event over vertex. I'll try with polyline's mousemove but It is fired after move has finished.
In the next code, I show an example what I said. I have a polyline (flightPath). If I click on the last vertex I will like to move a marker at the same time. But It doesn't work. The marker is moved after movement is finished.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'mousemove', function (event) {
   if (typeof event.vertex === "undefined") {
        moveline = 0
   }
   else {
       if (event.vertex == (flightPath.getPath().getLength()-1)) {
            var path = flightPath.getPath();
            marker.setPosition(path.getAt(event.vertex));
       }
   }
});
```

Some suggestion?

Note: My polyline is editable.

Thanks

Comment: [bind the marker position to the vertex's position](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCObject)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but It doesn't work as I want. Prior to post this question I tried with the google map example [link](http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/v3test/mvc/poly_bind.html) for binding markers to vertex, but my polyline is editable = true. Then I can move a vertex without move the marker although they are binded.

Answer (score 0):

You could manage a drag end event on the marker and change de latLng of the vertex:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(evt){

var vertex = marker.get('vertex');

var path = flightPath.getPath();

var newPath = Array.prototype.slice.call(path).filter(
function(element, index){
    return index < vertex;
}).concat([evt.latLng],
Array.prototype.slice.call(path).filter(
function(element, index){
    return index > vertex;
}));
flightPath.setPath(newPath);


});
```

I'm sorry for my bad english but i hope it helps.